How can fine tune VGG16 with gray images?
I am trying to use pre trained VGG16 with SRGAN and grayscale images when I use the VGG16 in this way:
def build_vgg():
    input_shape = (256, 256, 3)
    # Load a pre-trained VGG19 model trained on 'Imagenet' dataset
    
    vgg = VGG19(weights="imagenet",include_top=False, 
     input_shape=input_shape)
    vgg.trainable = False
return Model(inputs=vgg.inputs, outputs=vgg.layers[10].output)

my model work without any problem and gave grayscale images but when trying to frees the layers of VGG16 and train some layes like this code:
def build_vgg():
    """
    Build the VGG network to extract image features
    """
    input_shape = (256, 256, 3)
    vgg = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
   
    # Set the layers to be frozen
    for layer in vgg.layers[:8]:
        layer.trainable = False

    # Set the layers to be trainable
    for layer in vgg.layers[8:]:
        layer.trainable = True

    output_layer = vgg.get_layer('block5_conv4').output
    input_layer = vgg.input
    print(vgg.summary())
    model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
    return model

The generated images be like have blue filter and some time brown filter or all generated images in blue. why this happen and how can I fine tune the VGG16 with gray images??

The VGG16 model was originally trained on RGB images. To use ImageNet weights,
your input images should also be RGB. You can either convert grayscale images
to RGB or train VGG16 from scratch on grayscale images by intializing ramdom
weights.Please refer this document
